# Django Update Object in Database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to run a simple update form that should update all object values in DB submitted from the form.

This is my update view that does nothing other than redirecting to the "/". No errors but no update either.

```
def update(request, business_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BusinessForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            t = Business.objects.get(id=business_id)
            t.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
          ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating any fields, use [`form.cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form) to get the form field values:

> Once is_valid() returns True, the successfully validated form data
>   will be in the form.cleaned_data dictionary. This data will have been
>   converted nicely into Python types for you.

```
if form.is_valid():
    t = Business.objects.get(id=business_id)
    t.my_field = form.cleaned_data['my_field']
    t.save()
```

Also, consider using an [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) class-based generic view instead of a function-based:

> A view that displays a form for editing an existing object,
>   redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and
>   saving changes to the object. This uses a form automatically generated
>   from the object’s model class (unless a form class is manually
>   specified).

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I thought, I just wasnt sure if Django is smart enough to grab all the values from the form as it is done with saving new data or if I have to define each field.

Comment: @WayBehind django is smart enough if you would use an `UpdateView` - I've also updated the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wasnt aware of the UpdateView and will look into that!